# MS Access and SQL - Unknown Error and Count(Distinct) problems

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.

```
[Letter Status]

Letter_ID       Customer_ID*        Letter_Status
```

and

```
[Customer Details]

Customer_ID*        Ethnicity        Gender
```

The * denotes the INNER JOIN.

I want to count the number of Letter_Status = 'Complete' for ALL Male customers, for EACH ethnicity.

```
SELECT Ethnicity, Count(Letter_Status) AS N
FROM [Customer Details] INNER JOIN [Letter Status]
ON [Customer Details].Customer_ID = [Letter Status].Customer_ID
WHERE [Gender] = 'Male'
AND [Letter_Status] = 'Complete'
ORDER BY Ethnicity;
```

I get this error:

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Ethnicity' as part of an aggregate function"

I don't know how to fix this- I've tried everything I know how.

My second problem is my query will not be identifying OR ordering my results by unique (or DISTINCT) Ethnicity. Assuming someone can help me get past the above error (and I'm optimistic that they will), my data will look like this:

```
Ethnicity           N

Asian               1
Caucasian           1
Hispanic            1
Asian               1
Hispanic            1
```

when really, I need it to look like this:

```
Ethnicity           N

Asian               12
Caucasian           9
Hispanic            7
```

I am pretty sure I need the Count(Distinct) function, but unfortunately, I am stuck with MS Access 2007 and this is not supported.

I found this description, but it just confused me and I could not successfully apply it to my data.

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx

Comment: As regards your second part (count distinct), how about using two queries, first to apply the `DISTINCT` and the second to use the first to do the count.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a group by ethnicity.

```
SELECT Ethnicity, COUNT(*) as EthnicityCount
FROM [Customer Details] INNER JOIN [Letter Status]
ON [Customer Details].Customer_ID = [Letter Status].Customer_ID
WHERE [Gender] = 'Male'
AND [Letter_Status] = 'Complete'
GROUP BY Ethnicity
ORDER BY Ethnicity;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please help me out with the second part?

Comment: Grouping by Ethnicity should give you unique counts of distinct entries, which is what you want?

Comment: I'm trying have the total count for each Ethnicity. I'm not sure, but there may be something else wrong with my code because there are no results coming up from this query. So frustrating

Comment: Add COUNT(*) to get the total count of each ethnicity

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Could you please edit the code above with the Count(*). I don't want to take any chances here :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `GROUP BY Ethnicity]` your your query.

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway you could please help me out with the second part (ordering by distinct values)